# Showing both the value and index in the x-ticks in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot something using `plot(x,y)` and be able to see on the plot the index of the value in `x`

For example.

```
x = [10,30,100,120]
y = [16,17,19,3]
plot(x,y)
```

will show

[image]

looking at the plot it is hard to know at every point what was the original index. For example I want to be able to know when looking at the point (100,19) that it is index 2, since `x[2]=100` and `y[2]=19`.
How do I do that in matplotlib.
I looked at `twiny()` function but that seems to just add another axes disregarding the distance between points in x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [10,30,100,120]
y = [16,17,19,3]
plt.plot(x,y);
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    plt.annotate(str(i), xy=(a, b), textcoords="offset points", xytext=(0, 12),
                 horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
plt.xlim(0, 130)
plt.ylim(0, 22)
```

What it does: it enumerates on your `y` and `x` arrays, storing the index in the variable `i` and the respective values of `x` and `y` in the variables `a` and `b`. It then annotates the index `i` at the coordinates `(a, b)`, offsetting the text by 12 pixels on the y-axis to avoid the annotation covering the curve.

The result:

[image]

Comment: For very large graph, i.e 1000s of points it might run slowly by otherwise  this is fine. Thanks!